# How use return statement?

Tags: php

I have such code:

```
class test(){
   #some operation to get $data
   function test1($data){
      #save some part of data
      return $save
   }
   function test2($data, $save(!!!)){
   #some operation
   }
}
```

Question: how use variable `$save` in `test2()` which return from `test1()`?

Comment: show how are you calling those functions.

Comment: When your code calls `test2()` it can pass the value that it received when it called `test1()`.  *Edit:* Or, since you've edited your code to use a class, you can define your value as a class-level member which both functions can access.

Comment: @urfusion ` $this->test1($data)`

Comment: use `$fun1 = $this->test1($data); $this->test2($data,$fun1);`

Comment: `return $save` remember to close that off, you'll get an error for it. Hint: Missing the semi-colon for it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be an alternative solution but as far as I see, you lack of OOP knowledge. I would recommend to read [PHP-OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) first.

Here I write you a simple and clean class structure, to make it more understandable.

```
class Test {

    private $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
       $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function setData($data) {

      $this->data = $data;          

      return $this;
    }

    public function getData() {

        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

Now you are able to set/get the data:

```
 $test2 = new Test("Save my text");
 $test1 = $test2
          ->setData("Changing my text...")
          ->getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

write code this way

```
<?php
class test{ //class no reuqire ()
  function test1($data)
  { 
          $save=$data+10;    //$data assign in $save
          #save some part of data
          return $save; //return $save value
  }
   function test2($data){
        $data=$this->test1($data); //call a test1() function from test2()
        echo $data; //print return data from test1()
   }
}
$new=new test(); //create object of class test
$new->test2(20);//call test2() function using class object $new
```

demo:[run demo code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f55077f110778ed70eefb4082588917414877296)